# How to make redux store in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-tsx

I want to make a react redux using typescript but got an error. I use cra redux typescript template for the installation. I delete the counter reducer, and a new reducer using slice.

I want to specify my error is in the initialState at userSlice.ts with the following error.

[image]

[image]

Here is type.ts

```
export interface ExplicitContent {
  filter_enabled: boolean;
  filter_locked: boolean;
}

export interface ExternalUrls {
  spotify: string;
}

export interface Followers {
  href?: any;
  total: number;
}

export default interface UserType {
  country: string;
  display_name: string;
  explicit_content: ExplicitContent;
  external_urls: ExternalUrls;
  followers: Followers;
  href: string;
  id: string;
  images: any[];
  product: string;
  type: string;
  uri: string;
}
```

Here is userSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import UserType from '../../types/user';

interface UserState {
  user: UserType;
  token: string;
}

const initialState: UserState= {
  user: null,
  token: '',
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setToken(state, action) {
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload,
      };
    },
    setUser(state, action) {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    },
  },
});
```

I don't know if my reducer or the initialstate have a wrong syntax or something. I use [json2ts.com](http://json2ts.com/) to change json response from the api call, so I think there is no problem about it. But I'm not sure about my code in the reducer. Please give me solution for this, thank you in advance.

#note: I'm not changing anything about hooks.ts and store.ts from the template except the configurestore to import my reducer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `initialState` variable needs to be `UserState`. Additionally, `user` property in `UserState` currently cannot be `null`, hence you will have to add a `null` union type to it in order for `initialState` to be valid.

```
interface UserState {
  user: UserType | null;
  token: string;
}
```

```
const initialState: UserType = {
  user: null,
  token: '',
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it works fine now. But I want to ask something, I tried to change the initialState to `const initialState: UserState | {} = {code}` but not work. Is this wrong use of `null` type?

Comment: I am not sure what ```code``` is. But given that it is not part of ```UserState``` type, I would say that it is incorrect.

Comment: If my answer helped with your original question, would you mind accepting it :)

Comment: Oops sorry forgot it. And yes, I can't declare initial state like that, just see the documentation